# Inheritance nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, prototype

I'm trying to inherate a module in nodejs. When I call super only one time, it's ok, but when I started to call it in other code points, data from one is in another...

RegEvent.js (super)

```
var __ = require('lodash');
var RegEvent = function () {
    RegEvent.prototype.Model = new require('models/regValids')(this.model);
};

RegEvent.prototype.getAll = function () {
    var self = this;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    var callback = args.pop();
    getAll(self, args[0], args[1] || {}, args[2] || {}, callback);
};
var getAll = function (scope, company, where, projection, callback) {
    scope.Model.get(company, where, projection, function (error, result) {
        return callback(error, result);
    });
};
module.exports = RegEvent;
```

configPerEmployee.js

```
var __ = require('lodash');
var inherits = require('util').inherits;
var RegEvent = require('components/regEvent');

var ConfigPerEmployee = function () {
    this.model = 'config_employees';
    RegEvent.apply(this, arguments);
};

inherits(ConfigPerEmployee, RegEvent);

ConfigPerEmployee.prototype.handlePriority = function (company, employee, callback) {
...
}
```

So, I have another module called schedules (like configPerEmployee.js) that inherits RegEvents and when I call `getAll function` from schedules, I access model from configPerEmployee. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: I guess that node with ES6 would be much easier for getting this kind of behaviours because you can create classes

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're reassigning `RegEvent.prototype.Model` each time you create an instance of `ConfigPerEmployee` etc.

Why don't you change the RegEvent constructor to

```
var RegEvent = function(modelName) {
  this.Model = new require('models/regValids')(modelName);
}
```

and ConfigPerEmployee etc. to

```
var ConfigPerEmployee = function() {
    RegEvent.apply(this, ['config_employees']);
};
```